# Excel Copy-Paste formatting efficiencies

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-formatting

I have an upcoming project in Excel that will involve a lot of manual copy and pasting from one workbook to another. I have large amounts of documentation made in excel that need to get copy and pasted from an original workbook to one with XML tags in the header.

This documentation is heavily formatted with lots of text (and rows resized to fit) and images embedded in the document with rows resized to fit the image size or images resized to fit the row height. I am starting with just a select all then copy paste.

It will be a large amount of documentation to convert so I am looking to establish an efficient method early on. For column width, I plan to use Paste Special option that keeps column width the same. For row height, it seems my best solution is to use format painter on all of the rows from source to new document. After that, the last issue is the image size as many images will not fit the cell row they are on after pasting. See an example below. Is there any solution to keep the image size from the original document? Obviously I'd rather avoid have to manually resize every image.

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there would be a good way to format your pictures.

Best workaround I think would be to copy the entire worksheet into your new workbook and paste XML tags in the header.